# PO, MO translation files

Tags: php, translation, gettext, po, mo

I want make a multi-language app I heard about `.po` files but I can't locate it I made this code

I made a directory in my application called `languages` and I put the `ar_EG.po` file in it
and I tried `languages\ar\LC_MESSAGES` but it dosen't work too

```
putenv('LC_ALL=ar_EG');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_EG', 'ara_EGY');

$domain = 'ar_EG';
bindtextdomain($domain, "./languages"); // I think the error here
textdomain($domain);

// to verify that localization is enabled and it works as intended:
echo strftime("%A %B %Y", strtotime("01/30/2013")), "<br>";

echo gettext("login"); // here not working
```

Comment: Please double check return values in your code. E.g. `bindtextdomain` does return a value. Which is it? Also we don't see you `.po` file here, it might just not contain an entry for `"login"`. You need to do some basic troubleshooting first to find out more.

Comment: it returns the path of the language directory

Comment: if that value is correct - only you can say - then the error *is not* there where you left the comment in your example code above. You need to trouble-shoot further.

Comment: ok it's done the server must be restarted before running

Comment: Maklard: Which SAPI is your PHP using? (see [`php_sapi_name`](http://php.net/php_sapi_name) or [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo)). Are you running PHP as an Apache module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server must be restarted after editing. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your po file into a mo file, and put that in there instead...

Also, you need to make sure that GetText is installed...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: @MostafaMaklad: Dig it: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html - also google has more PHP centric resources if you just google for it.